# Alter plaintext through IV in block cipher AES in CBC mode

Tags: aes, cbc, initialization-vector

IV: 69bb375aa919c72aa561dd7b7ffacf66

Ciphertext: "c28ea025d10186510855d083747d6435c808d9857075abd9bfc54b094e60eaf3"

Plaintext: "SEND ENCRYPTED DATA"

I want to be able to change the resulting Plaintext to "SEND THE DATA", which if I understand correctly would involve altering the IV in this case.

I have read about the bit flipping and how this attack works, I am just having troubles implemeting it in this scenario, please help.

below the encryption (at the server side- we were given the code), includes the padding used,

```
  def encrypt(plaintext):
            log.info("[%d] encrypt data command invoked" % (client_id))
            iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
```

`# add padding
        if (len(plaintext) % 16 != 0):
            plaintext += b"_" * (16 - len(plaintext) % 16)

        cipher = AES.new(shared_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

        return hexlify(iv) + b"," + hexlify(ciphertext) + b"\n"

   def no_tranform(plaintext):
        log.info("[%d] send data command invoked" % (client_id))
        return hexlify(plaintext) + b"\n"

    commands = {"SEND ENCRYPTED DATA": encrypt,
                "SEND THE DATA": no_tranform}`

Also you can see that the only allowed commands are "SEND ENCRYPTED DATA" and "SEND THE DATA" and I would like the latter.

Comment: Some more details would be welcome. Exactly what have you tried, and what kind of "troubles" have you had?

Comment: Also, does the modified plaintext have to be _exactly_ "SEND THE DATA"? Because it would be easier to do this if you didn't have to change the length of the plaintext. (You can probably still do it in this case anyway, but the details will depend on the padding scheme used.)

Comment: @llmari Karonen please check my new edit, thank you

Comment: This is off-topic here. programming Questions belongs to SO.

Comment: @kelalaka: I would say that this question can be interpreted and answered in a way that is on-topic here (i.e. the answer does not necessarily need to include any code). Whether such an answer would actually help the OP is still somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: BTW, here's a hint to begin with: start by figuring out which [padding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) is used. (I'd guess it's most likely PKCS#7, but there are several other possibilities as well.) Then apply the padding to both plaintexts. Now try to figure out what else, besides bit flipping, you'd need to do to turn one into the other. Can you do that just by manipulating the ciphertext?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen What I've understood, he wants to modify the IV in a way that the original plaintext `SEND ENCRYPTED DATA|Padding_1` will turn into `SEND DATA|padding_2`. But the problem is the second block. `SEND ENCRYPTED ` 15 char. One can change `SEND DATA      ` by changing the IV. But the second block is problematic. He needs to modify the first ciphertext, too. So, he must first consider changing the $C_1$ then concentrate on `IV`. (assuming that 16 char is encrypted per block)

Answer (score 1):

Each bit you flipped in the IV changes the same bit in the decrypted plaintext. So if you want to change the first `E` character of `ENCRYPTED` into a `T` of `THE` then you need to XOR the binary representation of `E` and `T` (probably ASCII) and XOR that with the byte in the IV. This will of course only work for the first block of 16 bytes. Fortunately `"SEND THE DATA"` is small enough for that (13 bytes if I count correctly).

That leaves the problem of the padding. The original block contains the padding in the second block because of the size (19 bytes). However, you just have to adjust the padding of the first block by performing the XOR as displayed above. Instead of XOR'ing the final 16 - 3 = 3 plaintext bytes with a letter you XOR them with the value `03` in hex and XOR that with the IV. Now you've also generated the required padding.

Finally, you need to leave out the second block. And that's all me wrote, happy programming.